# .htaccess rewrite rule for forcefully redirect https to http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a primary domain `https://www.domain.com` or `https://domain.com` and a wildcard DNS like `https://domain.com/index.php?name=abcd` redirect on forcefully `http://abcd.domain.com` but I have another problem my login page is `https://domain.com/login.php?name=abcd` and I want result like forcefully `http://domain.com/login.php?name=abcd` but it cannot redirect on HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On

#match either the www subdomain or no subdomain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
#which request index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php
#and contain a username paramater
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)(?:^|&)name=([^&]+)(.*?)$
#then rewrite them to name.domain.com without the name parameter
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#match either the www subdomain or no subdomain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
#which was requested without https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#then redirect to https
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]




#Capture subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(?:domain\.com)$
#If we're not working on www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www.domain\.com)$
#If querystring doesn't contain name
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*?)(?:^|&)name=([^&]+)(.*?)$
#Add username to querystring
RewriteRule index.php index.php?name=%1 [L,QSA]
```

this htaccess code is working fine but i want login script in htaccess

---

After clarification in chat, this is what I need:

All URLs should be rewritten to `https`, except `login.php`, which should stay at `http`. If `login.php` comes in as `https`, rewrite it to `http`.

Comment: I read your .htaccess, but I don't understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean with "I want login script in htaccess"?

Comment: i want to say i want this result  http://domain.com/login.php?name=abcd
my domain is https so its automatically redirect to https

Comment: And at what input do you want `/login.php?name=abcd`? Is it where you have `index.php` now  or in addition to it or maybe something else?

Comment: index.php is also in same directory

Comment: I still don't understand, *when* you want to see `login.php`. What should be the URL or condition to redirect to `login.php`?

Comment: ok i will telling you clearly in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90889/discussion-between-amy-and-olaf-dietsche).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the rule for rewriting to `https`, the only thing left is excluding `login.php`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login\.php$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

If `login.php` is requested *with* `https`, rewrite it to `http`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^login.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

---

Finally, a minor hint: *never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: where should i add these lines

Comment: Just add to your site's vhost_ssl.conf configuration (or .htaccess at the root of the site)

Comment: this line means all of the url redirect on http but i want only login.php redirect on http

Comment: maybe try something like this `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/folder/login.php$1 [R,L]`